# actionButton and if condition

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a complex shiny app with some internal default data. I added the possibility to update these internal data with new files (uploaded with `fileInput()`). I want that only after I click on a button, the default data and the new data merge together. I find this solution (just add any file in `fileInput()` to make it works).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3, fileInput("fileupaziendedata", "Carica il file csv")), #just load any file
    column(3, actionButton("mergeaziende", "Unisci"))), #the button that merges      
  hr(),
  dataTableOutput("summary_table")
  
)

server <- function(input,output){
  
  data = reactive({
    data.frame(id = c(1:5), lett = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
    })
  
  datafromfile = reactive({
    data.frame(id = c(6,7), lett = c("F", "G"))
  })
  
  data2 = reactive({
    
    if(!is.null(input$fileupaziendedata) && input$mergeaziende > 0){
        rbind(data(), datafromfile())
    }else{
      data()
    }
    
  })
  output$summary_table <- renderDataTable({
    data2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Now my problem is that since I used `input$mergeaziende > 0` condition, after the first button press, it will be always greater than 0. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this type of question come up before. Basically, how to "reset" the action button value. Here's my general solution. I reset a `reactiveVal` instead of trying to manipulate the input. Here the input will reset after 5, but it can be changed to something else (like when your data reactive triggers):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('click' ,'Click'),
  textOutput('counter_out')
)

server <- function(session, input, output){
  
  # initialize at -  0
  # this is the value to observe (not input$click)
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  output$counter_out <- renderText(counter())
  
  #increment per click
  observeEvent(input$click, counter(counter() + 1))
  
  observe({
    #WHEN you want the count reset 
    if(counter() > 5) counter(0)
   })                  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks but still it's not perfect because in my case I need that those if conditions work every time I press the button. So following your example, I need that after the first click (counter become 1), the app runs the if conditions and save the data and ONLY after that, it resets the counter. I tried to reset the counter at 1 but I think it's faster then the if conditions (because data2 is not updated).

Comment: Is there anyway to reset the counter inside the data2 reactive? Like for exampe   
`data2 = reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$fileupaziendedata) && counter() > 0){rbind(data(), datafromfile()) counter() = 0}else{data()}
    
  })`

Comment: You can reset the counter anywhere you like  just so long as it's in a reactive context (like inside your data2 reactive).    But you reset like this `counter(0)`, not `counter() = 0`